# Meaning and origin of British/Australian slang word 'tut'

Tags: british-english, slang, australian-english

About twenty years ago I overheard a girl from the north of England laughingly advise a friend to get ready for a night out by telling her to 'slap some tut on your face'. She clearly meant 'put on some make-up'.
I had already heard an Australian informally use the same, or a similar-sounding word, 'tut', to mean 'toilet'.

I have also seen it defined on a website of British slang as: 'tut  Noun. Rubbish, nonsense. E.g."Whatever he told you about me is just a load of tut." or "I think we need to clear up all this tut before your parents arrive."

Are the three meanings of make-up, toilet and rubbish linked by some excremental ur-word, and if so does anyone know the origin?

Comment: Your north of England example was possibly saying tut as slang for "to the" which is very common, but not in that context

Comment: (not a BrE speaker) Allow for the possibility that even if 'tut' as used by the friend might be a synonym for 'shit' or 'rubbish', it could be used figuratively for 'makeup' That is, makeup is not necessarily a synonym of 'tut', just that 'tut' is a filler word like 'stuff' or 'thing'. 'Slap some tut on your face 'could easily denote 'put something on your face'.

Comment: The only American usage I know of is Tut-Tut. Which I suspect is an appropriation from BE. But, as it means an expression of dismissive disappointment, the rubbish angle fits. Saying *that's rubbish* is fairly dismissive. As to the usage for makeup, it must mean rubbish as well. We Americans might say she *caked that crap* on her face, referring to a woman wearing too much makeup. Seems to follow a logical pathway.

Comment: @Mitch and in some parts or NW England "tut" or "t't" is thrown into sentences at will

Comment: @anthonyblake It seems in context to be the rubbish usage more than a regional colloquialism. Though, that is an interesting bit of information.  Do you know the reason/usage/origin?

Comment: I think the *tut=rubbish* sense is probably either a variant or a mishearing/mistranscription of ***tat***.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake I'm a northerner myself. Abbreviating 'the' to 't' is familiar to me.  And one might well say 'I'm goin' tut shops (in the sense of 'to t' or 'to the' shops)'; but one would never say 'I'm goin slap some 'to the' on me face.'  It makes no sense.

Comment: @slam 'I'm goin' slap some tut face.' makes perfect northern sense. the word makeup is simply dropped (lots of words are dropped in NW England) and "to the" is abbreviated. Infact, "slap" is also slang for makeup making it even clearer to a native. (I'm from Lancashire).

Comment: (Get some) slap [ie makeup] on t't face?

Comment: @slam how anyone form lancashire cannot understand this is beyond me

Comment: @peterG She could have meant that had she said, 'Get some slap on t't face.'  But at the risk of becoming boring, what she actually said was: 'Slap (imperative verb) some tut (unknown noun) on your face.'  Come on, guys. I was there.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake It's the syntax I think.  See reply above to peterG.

Comment: Fair enough, you were there. But, given the fallibility of memory and possibility of mishearing, etc etc my suggestion (as a northener myself) is the only way I can think of to jam those words together to mean what you say she meant. . .ie 'slap' was meant as a noun, but you heard it as a verb, and the rest followed.

Comment: The Australian may have said toot, rather than tut. Toot is Australian slang for toilet, although I don't think it is very common. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/toot

Comment: Thanks - the Australian who used the expression was born in the 1930s so it is quite likely it's older/obsolete slang.

Comment: @peterG exactly

Comment: But then to my astonishment I find Mary Portas, quoted in the Guardian, Sat 17th May2014: "when I read some niggly little bit of tut in the paper that 'they've spent £250 learning how to gift wrap'"

Comment: @Anthony So you're saying that in Northern logic (and re-adding the noun), “Put some makeup to the on your face” makes sense? _To the on your_ certainly doesn't make **any** kind of sense to me, regardless of dialect.

Comment: No-one has commented that the word spelled *tut* is pronounced /tʊt/ in all the cases in the question, rather than /tʌt/. It could be spelled *toot* following the example of *took*.

Comment: If I heard someone say *tut*, I'd just assume it was short for *tut-tut*, which expresses disapproval.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the word 'tut' as a noun is, as of yet, unknown. The OED entry for Tut says:

> Etymology:  There is perhaps more than one word here. Of the origin nothing has been ascertained.

However, the use of the word 'tut' in the 'rubbish' sense may be supported by this definition from the OED:

> a. Orig. in the Cornish tin-mines, now also in Derbyshire lead-mining: in the phrase upon tut (also by the tut), and attrib. as tut-bargain, tut-man, tut-work (also as vb.), tut-worker, tut-working, tut-workman: denoting a system of payment by measurement or by the piece, adopted in paying for work which brings no immediate returns, as distinct from tribute n. 3; hence, work of this character; dead-work.

The OED takes less of a cop-out on Tut, v. saying:

> Etymology:  A natural utterance; the spelling tut sometimes represents the palatal click (also spelt tchick n., tck int.).

Which may also explain the etymology of the slang word - being something that is just replaced for a word that is better left unsaid - a sort of self-censorship of more appropriate or cruder language.

Ultimately my guess would be that it's some combination of the two.

Comment: I wondered if there was some remote connection to 'toute', which was used in Chaucer for 'buttocks, posterior, rump'. Acc. OED that derives from the root 'tut', 'to stick out or project'. A long time later I know, but in Victorian times those who scoured dust-heaps for recyclable refuse referred to bones as 'tots'; by 1880 any retrievable items you could pick out of rubbish were also called 'tots' (hence 'totting', and 'totter' as in Steptoe and Son.  Ignore that ref if you aren't British). Maybe the sense shifted from items found in rubbish to rubbish itself, and a general sense of 'crap'?

Comment: Pavja2, your explanation is the best I've come across for this word tut/toot (rhyming with 'put') I've used on a very frequent basis all my life. A few years ago I discovered that the vaste majority of people where I live (in Brighton, home to people from all over UK) do not know the word. I am from Essex and it's very commonly used there , to mean rubbish or, perjoratively, your own or someone else's belongings. "Your car's full of tut". I have deduced that it is a Cockney term as the people I've come across who do know it are from areas to which there's been London migration.(Mary Portas is

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you could ask her, but 20 years later that seems difficult. To me it could have referred to the meaning "shit" as in "Just put some shit on your face and let's go!" but the speaker was in fact referring to makeup but didn't really care or wasn't interested in the result or any backtalk from the intended recipient :)
(Canadian speaker but never heard the word before.)

Answer (score 0):

In the sense given, "rubbish" it seems to come from **tat**

OED:

> **tat, n.5**
>
> **Etymology**: Origin uncertain: compare Old English *tættec* a rag, and tatty adj.1
>
> slang.
>
> a. A rag; also (in singular), poorly made or tasteless clothes. Hence, a shabby person, a slut.
>
> 1839   H. Brandon Dict. Flash or Cant Lang. in W. A. Miles Poverty, Mendicity & Crime 168   *The paper makers get the tats and never tip the motts a posh.* [Translation] Thieves who pretend to belong to paper mills get the rags and never pay the women a farthing.

which gave rise to

> b. Rubbish, junk, worthless goods. Also transferred and figurative.
>
> 1951   W. Sansom Face of Innocence iv. 55   He was talking of his business in Georgian and early Victorian objets d'oeil. He called it tat.

Answer (score -1):

Tut derives from the German tot meaning dead. In the UK, a totter is another name for a rag and bone man who collects unwanted items by calling door-to-door.

Comment: "tot" seems to be slang for a bone, and the OED says it's possibly the origin of "totter", but the OED doesn't give anything else about its etymology (no link to German). A link to "tut" is possible but there's a lack of evidence (if "tut"/"tutter" was an alternative for tot/totter that would be evidence.)